# Spring boot angularjs security custom login issue

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I cant make custom login page work with angularjs and spring boot security . Default browser login form only get displayed.

I am able to authenticate and authorize the user but default login page gets displayed on first time. Also i get 302 status on logout.

Angular version : 1.4.8 , using ui-router.

Below is my main js .

```
    'use strict';

angular
  .module('renalyxNis', [
    'ui.router','ui.bootstrap' ,'chart.js','ngAnimate','ngResource','angular-timeline'])
  .config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';




    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider

       .state('dashboard', {
        url:'/dashboard',
        controller : 'starterCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'pages/starter2.html'

    })
      .state('dashboard.home',{
        url:'/home',
        controller : 'appointmentCtrl',
        templateUrl:'pages/home.html'

      })
      .state('dashboard.session',{
        url:'/session',       
        controller : 'sessionCtrl',
        templateUrl:'pages/session.html'

      })
      .state('dashboard.shiftmanagement',{
        url:'/shiftmanagement',        
        controller : 'shiftManageCtrl',
        templateUrl:'pages/shiftmanagement.html'

      })
      .state('dashboard.dialysisconfig',{
        url:'/dialysisconfig',       
        controller : 'dialysisConfigCtrl',
        templateUrl:'pages/dialysisconfig.html'

      })
      .state('dashboard.staffconfig',{
        url:'/staffconfig',       
        controller : 'staffCtrl',
        templateUrl:'pages/staff.html'

      })

      .state('login',{
        templateUrl:'login.html',
        url:'/login'
    });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {

        return {

            'responseError': function(rejection){

                var defer = $q.defer();

                if(rejection.status == 401){
                    console.dir(rejection);
                    console.log("rejected");
                    $state.go('login');
                }

                defer.reject(rejection);

                return defer.promise;

            }
        };
    });


  });
```

Login ctrl :

```
angular.module('renalyxNis')
.controller('LoginController',function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $state) {

    $rootScope.authenticated = false;

  var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

        var headers = credentials ? {authorization : "Basic "
            + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
        } : {};

        console.log("inside login");
        $http.get('user', {headers : headers}).success(function(data) {
            // $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            if (data.name) {
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                console.log("complete data");

                console.log(data);
                console.log('username :');
                $rootScope.username = (data.principal.username);
                $scope.username = (data.principal.username);
                console.log('auth :');
                $rootScope.roles = (data.principal.authorities); 
                console.log(data.principal.authorities);
                console.log('name');
                console.log(data.name);

                $scope.name = data.name;

            } else {
                console.log(data);
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            }
            callback && callback();
        }).error(function() {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            callback && callback();
        });

    }

    //authenticate();
    $scope.credentials = {};
    $scope.login = function() {

        console.log("credentials");
        console.log($scope.credentials);
        authenticate($scope.credentials, function() {
            if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
                console.log("authenticated")
                // $location.path("/home");
                $state.go ('dashboard');

                $scope.error = false;
            } else {
                $state.go('login');
                //  $location.path("/login");
                $scope.error = true;
            }
        });
        console.log("in login");
    };

    $scope.logout = function() {
        $http.post('logout', {}).success(function() {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            console.log("in logout");
            $state.go('login');
            //    $location.path("/login");
        }).error(function(data) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        });
    }

});
```

Websecurityconfig file :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("in configure1");
         http 
         .httpBasic().and()

         .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers( "/").permitAll()
           .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

           .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
           .permitAll().and()
           .formLogin()
           .loginPage("/login")
           .permitAll().and()         
           .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
           .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
               // .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        System.out.println("in configure");

    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
          HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
          repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
          return repository;
        }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        if(encoder == null) {
            encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        return encoder;
    }
}
```

CSRF header filter :

```
public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
      @Override
      protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
            .getName());
        if (csrf != null) {
          Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
          String token = csrf.getToken();
          if (cookie==null || token!=null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
          }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
    }
```

I referred from spring.io and dave syer login examples but to no avail.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I am also facing the same issue. Your comment below in @Jamone341 's answer to add /** fixes it but is it the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('login',{
    templateUrl:'login.html',
    url:'/login'
```

isn't specifying the LoginController so perhaps login.html doesn't get rendered properly?

Comment: Thanks , i tried but it didn't work . It works if i put "/**" in ant matchers

Answer (score 0):

When using with AngularJS be sure to use withHttpOnlyFalse():
    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())

as stated in 4.1 documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CookieCsrfTokenRepository.html[#withHttpOnlyFalse--](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CookieCsrfTokenRepository.html#withHttpOnlyFalse--)

... still receiving an 302 redirect from the server to the invalidSessionUrl if you did set it using 
`http.sessionManagement(). ... invalidSessionUrl("login url or so")`