# Spring Boot + Spring Security - unable to log out

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a REST API built with Spring Boot and Spring Security. I have read from the docs that Spring Security defaults to logging the current user out when they request `/logout`.  However, I can't seem to get this to work.

This is my security configuration:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    } 
}
```

However, when I make a request to `/logout`, I receive the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1485096094269,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/login"
}
```

Comment: You don't provide `.logout()`; see e.g. https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/. What request are you making?

Comment: I actually tried adding .logout(); from a couple of different examples I've seen, but to no effect. How you recommend changing the above example to enable logging out? The request I'm making is a GET request to "/logout".

Comment: Yep, configuration is definitely being called.  I added ".logout.permitAll()" I tried using the POST method to "/logout" and and still the same message and not logged out.  What do others use as a configure method?

Comment: Also trying to logout when using basic authentication is not going to work, The next request still sends the authentication headers and the user will be logged in again. Logout and basic auth don't go together.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that. So would you recommend using digest authentication instead? Or do I need to manually invalidate the session using a custom method with a "/logout" requestMapping?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it's a little late to answer this question, but anyone can be useful.

In the `configure()` method is missing the `logout()` invocation, for example:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
    .logout() // This is missing and is important
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
```

Also you can configure your own login page:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        // this allows the root and resources to be available without logging in
        .antMatchers("/", "/resources/**").permitAll()
        // any other type of request will need the credentials
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    // uses the custom login form
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home") // redirect to home page
        .failureUrl("/login?error") // redirect to error page
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    // logout and redirect to login page
    .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
```

Comment: Worked for the `logout` with me. Thank you

Comment: Logout still doesn't work for me. Get a 404. Copied the first block exactly.

Comment: @SledgeHammer It's possible that you don't have the `/logout` or `/login` resource, for that reason you're getting 404, you can try to update that part. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If using AngularJS check you use withHttpOnlyFalse()

```
.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43204307/1767316